# qmail bug, allows open relay to local addresses

Tags: smtp, email

```
Last login: Wed Jun 22 14:02:11 on ttys001
BASH$ telnet domain.com 25
Trying xxx.xx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 hostname.com ESMTP
helo
250 hostname.com
mail from: <danayoub53@gmail.com>
250 ok
rcpt to: <anyone@gmail.com>
553 sorry, that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts (#5.7.1)
rcpt to: <registration@domain.com>
250 ok  ***********<---------------------- OK??!?
```

As you can see, qmail blocks the attempt to send mail to an outside address, however has no problem allowing an un-authenticated user to send mail to local addresses residing on the server. This could pose problems if someone wanted to send viruses, or clog e-mail accounts on the server.

Can anyone recommend a fix for this? Am I correct in point out that this is a bug?

Best,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

SMTP has never required people to authenticate before sending email to accounts on the local machine. It is not a bug at all. How else would an SMTP server receive email to be delivered to the domains you are hosting email for?

Answer (score 0):

As X-Istence says, the question is fundamentally bogus.  *There is no such thing* as relay to a locally hosted mailbox.  It's a conceptual error.  Either the mailbox is remote, in which case the mail has to be stored and forwarded — i.e. relayed — to it, or the mailbox is local, in which case there is no relaying going on at all because the system is the final destination for the mail.

`rcpthosts`, which defines which domains the SMTP Relay server (`qmail-smtpd`) will accept in envelope recipient mailboxes, is (usually) the union of all locally hosted domains and all domains for which mail is permitted to be relayed.  That it has allowed a message from the outside world to be addressed to a locally hosted mailbox isn't an error.  It's working as designed.  If you do not want the outside world to be able to send mail to you, *do not run an SMTP Relay server*.  Running an SMTP Relay server implies that you *do* want the outside world to be able to send mail to you.

The notion of authorization applies, obviously enough, to *local* users that you have a user database for, and thus applies to SMTP Submission, not to SMTP Relay.  If you've been confused by the [Old-Fashioned Mail Injection Protocol](http://thedjbway.b0llix.net/mess822/ofmipd.html) into thinking that SMTP Relay deals in authorization (when, of course, there's no way for you to have a user database listing the arbitrary people in South Africa or India or France who might want to send mail to you) then you need to re-familiarize yourself with the difference between SMTP Submission and SMTP Relay.  This is the 21st century; we know about service separation nowadays; we shouldn't be using the OFMIP paradigm any more.